# Nested styles in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have:

```
\pgfkeys{/TransformerNetwork/.style={
        transformer/.style 2 args={draw, cylinder, gray!80, rotate=90, minimum height=#1, minimum width=#2},
        }}
```

And then:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[/TransformerNetwork]
    \node [transformer={2.3cm}{1cm}] () at (0,0.6) {};
```

but tikz complains:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfkeys@temp.
```

How do I let it know that the 2 arguments are for the nested style?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with Jake that there's no need here to nest the *definitions* of the styles, but just in case a more complicated situation comes along where you do need to nest them (or at least, not being able to do so becomes a really hassle), the solution to the problem is simple and is essentially the same problem as nesting definitions.

That is to say, if you put the following code in a document

```
\def\a{\def\b#1{got #1}}
```

you will get exactly the same error message:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \a.
```

So what's happening here is that something is getting `\def`ed behind the scenes and the contents of the style is getting transformed in to the body of that `\def`.  This means that the `#1` and `#2` are interpreted as the arguments of the *outer* style.  The way to get them to work as you expect is to double the hashes.  That is to say,

```
\def\a{\def\b##1{got ##1}}
```

works: when `\a` is executed it is replaced in the stream by `\def\b#1{got #1}`.

Translated back in to your style, this becomes:

```
\pgfkeys{/TransformerNetwork/.style={
        transformer/.style 2 args={draw, rectangle, gray!80, rotate=90, minimum height=##1, minimum width=##2},
        }}
```

and now it works as you want it to.

It's good that you tried this with a style with *2* arguments as you wouldn't have gotten an error with one argument since styles can *by default* take an argument.  That is,

```
\pgfkeys{/TransformerNetwork/.style={
        transformer/.style 2 args={draw, rectangle, gray!80, rotate=90, minimum size=#1},
        }}
```

does not produce an error, but the value substituted in at `#1` needs to be provided by the `TransformerNetwork` style and *not* the `transformer` style.  Any argument provided to the `transformer` style would be thrown away.

It is, of course, possible to pic 'n' mix this syntax, and to good effect.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
% \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21414/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/TransformerNetwork/.style 2 args={
        transformer/.style 2 args={draw=#1, rectangle, rotate=#2, minimum height=##1, minimum width=##2},
        }}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[/TransformerNetwork={red}{50}]
    \node [transformer={2.3cm}{1cm}] () at (0,0.6) {};
    \node [transformer={2cm}{1.5cm}] () at (3,0.6) {};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[/TransformerNetwork={green}{80},yshift=-3cm]
    \node [transformer={2.3cm}{1cm}] () at (0,0.6) {};
    \node [transformer={2cm}{1.5cm}] () at (3,0.6) {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: nested style definitions]

Comment: Amazing!  Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.  My example is actually more complicated.  I had pruned it down to make it easier on answerers.

Comment: Note that at each level, the number of # is doubled, so at level 3 you need ####1.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't nest the *definitions* of the styles. Define the inner one (`transformer`) and then call that in the definition of the outer style (`TransformerNetwork`). Also, `TransformerNetwork` should be a `.style 2 args` so it can handle the two parameters that are then passed on to the inner style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}  
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{
        /tikz/transformer/.style 2 args={
            draw,
            cylinder, gray!80,
            rotate=90,
            minimum height=#1,
            minimum width=#2
        },
        /TransformerNetwork/.style 2 args={
        transformer={#1}{#2},
        }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [/TransformerNetwork={2.3cm}{1cm}] () at (0,0.6) {};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I clarified in my question what I was trying to do, but in fact, I can just do what you suggest since all of my "transformer"s are the same size.